# Is an array required to be initialized if I will read file contents into it?

Tags: arrays, rust

I am initializing `buf` unnecessarily with all zeros before immediately writing over its contents with `read_exact`:

```
fn parse<R: Read>(r: &mut R) -> Result<()> {
    let mut buf = [0u8; 1024];
    r.read_exact(&mut buf)?;
    // Do things to buf
    Ok(true)
}
```

While I don't think the 0-initialization is very time-consuming, it doesn't seem necessary. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Check the machine code first. I know C and C++ compilers will remove writes that are overwritten by other writes, if it can see the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, such an initialization is required in safe Rust. The compiler isn't necessarily able to tell that the *combination* of `read_exact` **and** `?` will prevent accesses to any uninitialized data from the array. The optimizing passes may make it better, but that cannot be counted on to work.

You could instead read into a `Vec`, which internally guarantees to never allow access to the uninitialized memory:

```
fn parse<R: Read>(r: &mut R) -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut buf = vec![]; // Can optionally use `Vec::with_capacity`
    r.take(1024).read_to_end(&mut buf)?;
    // Do things to buf
    Ok(())
}
```

---

In unsafe Rust, you can use `mem::uninitialized`. Make sure you understand all the terrible little nuances involved before choosing such a situation! Reading uninitialized memory is undefined behavior in Rust, so **you** must make absolutely sure that you prevent it from ever happening.

Here, we rely on:

1. The fact that `read_exact` will return an error if it didn't populate all of the bytes.
2. The fact that the *destructor* of `[u8; 1024]` will not read the bytes. This is important path to consider when an error occurs or if a panic is raised.

```
fn parse<R: Read>(r: &mut R) -> io::Result<()> {
    unsafe {
        let mut buf: [u8; 1024] = mem::uninitialized();
        r.read_exact(&mut buf)?;
        // Do things to buf
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

I wouldn't think this is would be worth it without heavy profiling.

Comment: By making `buf` uninitialized, wouldn't there be a possibility of buf being freed while still being uninitialized memory (which is UB)? E.g if `read_exact` failed before writing anything into it, either from a panic or returning an error. If so, I don't think it should be included in this answer without a disclaimer.

Comment: @Timidger fair point — whenever I see `unsafe` I treat the code with extreme suspicion, but having an explicit warning is always smart. In this case, I do believe it to be safe for the reasons I've added.

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no way to do this with `read_exact` in Rust outside of `unsafe` blocks. However, you can probably get what you want in this particular case by [using `std::io::BufReader::with_capacity`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html#method.with_capacity) instead of allocating your own `mut [u8]`.

If you don't care about being able to set the buffer length yourself, you could have your function require [the `std::io::BufRead` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html) for its argument instead of `Read`.

Either of the approaches I mentioned will allow you to use `fill_buf` and `consume` instead of `read_exact`, which should give you the performance you want.